# undefined in title FullCalendar (3.4.0 )

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, momentjs, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar-3

I had the same issue , 
"undefinedundefinedundefinedundefined" in title , I had no log error in Chrome Developer Tools

[image: Error Screenshot]

My Layout :

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/locale/fr.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/VisiteCalendar.js"></script>
```

My VisiteCalednar.js script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


var sourceFullView = { url: '/Vue_visite/GetEvents/' };
//var sourceSummaryView = { url: '/Home/GetDiarySummary/' };
var CalLoading = true;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


    customButtons: {
        AgendaWeek: {
            text: 'Semaine',
            click: function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
            }
        },
        AgendaDay: {
            text: 'Jour',
            click: function () {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaDay');
            }
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,AgendaWeek,AgendaDay'
    },

    // //editing
    editable: true,
    disableDragging: true,
    disableResizing: true,
    slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
    defaultDate: moment(),
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views     
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    nowIndicator: true,

    weekends: true,
    weekNumbers: true,
    weekNumbersWithinDays: true,

    showNonCurrentDates: true,

    locale: 'fr',
    lang: 'fr',
    timezone: 'Europe/Paris',
    allDaySlot: false,
    allDayDefault: true,
    eventLimit: true,


    // jquery-ui theming
    theme: false,
    height: 515,
    aspectRatio: 2,

    forceEventDuration: true,

    businessHours: {
        // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
        dow: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday - Thursday

        start: '8:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
        end: '18:00', // an end time (6pm in this example)
    },
    minTime: "08:00:00",
    maxTime: "18:00:00",


    //selectable: false,
    unselectAuto: true,

    dropAccept: '*',

    handleWindowResize: true,
    events: '/Vue_visite/GetEvents/',

    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#modalTitle').html(event.url);
        $('#modalBody').html(event.descriptionComplete);
        $('#eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
        $('#fullCalModal').modal();
    },

dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#eventTitle').val("");
    $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
    $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
    ShowEventPopup(date);
}

});});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reply is here: [jQuery fullCalendar displayed undefined on title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227050/jquery-fullcalendar-displayed-undefined-on-title)

In my case, loading moment.js fixed the issue.